# AppleScript to map network drive with username in path?

Tags: applescript

I am attempting to make a script that will map users folders on our network. 
I wanted to know if there is a way to pull the user name of who is logged in and add it to the path of the folder I am attempting to map.

For example:

```
mount volume "smb://server/users/user name"
```

I know I can use the following lines to pull the current user. But how would I apply that information to the volume mount path I am attempting?

```
tell application "System Events"
      name of current user
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
set {shortUserName, homeDirectory} to {short user name, POSIX path of home directory} of (system info)
mount volume "smb://server/users/" & shortUserName
```

As the short user name must not contain space characters it's not necessary to quote the name

Comment: is there a way to query ad to copy the path of that home directory? our AD is not set up with normal domainName/Users but domainName/companyName/Users

Comment: What do you mean with `query ad`?

Comment: I was trying to search Active Directory to get the path for each users Home Folder. But I figured out the issue. It had nothing to do with may code either,  which I am happy about.

Comment: I updated the answer to add the standard home directory of the current user which is also in the `system info` record

Answer (score -1):

Answered my own Question

```
set userName to (do shell script "echo $USER")
```